# ckeditor 5 online builder not showing

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I used the ckeditor 5 online builder, downloaded a zipped file. I unzipped it and created an html file to include the editor as follow :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>College Connect</title>

    <script src="ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
            .then(editor => {
                console.log(editor);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

that's not working and produces this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined`
however, when i used the full version from [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/download/) , it worked fine.

Is there something i need to do before using the online builder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDN in script tag instead of using downloaded file (provided in ckeditor.com itself).
It will work.
Else you are supposed to put your html file in the same folder in which your unzipped file exist or you can provide correct path of your downloded file in the script tag.

Comment: They are in the same folder. I don't want to use cdn, i use it in my android app and want to use it offline.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the toolbar this way worked for me.

```js
let editor;

ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#id-textarea'), {
  toolbar: [
    'heading',
    'bold',
    'italic',
    'underline',
    'fontFamily',
    'fontSize',
    'fontColor',
    'undo',
    'redo',
    'alignment',
    'indent',
    'list',
    'horizontalLine',
    'paragraph',
    'removeFormat',
    'specialCharacters',
    'wordCount',
  ],
})
  .then((newEditor) => {
    editor = newEditor;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```